# C# runtime compilation fails to run method with default value -- parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, reflection

hi I've done runtime  compilation.
targeted provider to .net 4

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
options.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0");
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider(options);
```

but when trying to call a method that has parameters with default values, without providing those parameters I get the parameter mismatch exception
any idea?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.missing.aspx), you can pass `Type.Missing` as a value for default parameters. And the only limitation - is the order of parameters.

Comment: interesting, but I do not know how many type missing are.... I'm doing some script runner I do not know neither method name nor num of parameters so cannot add the type missing cause I do not know when to add it. yet I do not understand why this does not work I'd expect it to work as .net 4 works without specifying the type.missing?